# Obtener el último resultado de una consulta en mysql

Tags: mysql

Necesito obtener solo el último registro que me arroja la siguiente consulta:

```
select Fecha from dim_tiempo dt
where Anio = 2023 and Laborable = 1 and Festivo = 0 and Fecha > '2023-03-29' 
LIMIT 15
```

El resultado de la anterior consulta es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero obtener solo el registro que está en el recuadro rojo.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes lograrlo con [`MAX()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_max):

```
select 
    MAX(Fecha) AS Fecha 
from dim_tiempo dt
where 
    Anio = 2023 
    and Laborable = 1 
    and Festivo = 0 
    and Fecha > '2023-03-29'
```

Comment: Entiendo el problema es que de esa forma me da como resultado el último día del año que cumpla con esas condiciones, yo solo necesito a partir de la fecha suministrada contar 15 días y obtener el último día de esos 15 días, por eso había puesto el limit 15

Comment: @Hamiltonps ¿`Fecha` es de tipo `DATETIME`?

Comment: Fecha es de tipo Date

Comment: @Hamiltonps ¿hay algo que describa la lógica que intentas seguir aquí? Me refiero al hecho de querer obtener los últimos 15 registros. Pregunto porque veo que hay saltos de fechas en esos valores, entonces no hablamos de resultados del tipo *intervalo de 15 días*, sino de algo parecido a *los próximos 15 resultados*. Quisiera saber la lógica que define eso, porque una solución puede aplicar para unos casos, pero no para otros.

Comment: El Limit 15 son los próximos 15 días que cumplan con las condiciones de la consulta, pero así como son 15 pueden ser 30 o 25, etc. en definitiva cualquier número de días. Los saltos de fechas obedecen a que solo estoy seleccionando los días que sean Laborables y que no sean Festivos, mi tabla tiene esos dos campos ambos de tipo booleano.

Answer (score 0):

La solución fue realizar una subconsulta reemplacé la fecha hardocodeada por now() y el año harcodeado year(now()) para que tengan la fecha del día actual y el año actual respectivamente, esto porque mi tabla dim_tiempo tiene el registro de todos los días de muchos años diferentes entonces debo decirle de qué año hará la búsqueda

```
select * from(select Fecha
from dim_tiempo dt
where Anio = year(NOW()) 
and Laborable = 1 
and Festivo = 0 
and Fecha > now()
LIMIT 15) as fecha
order by fecha DESC 
limit 1
```